# Unexpected Output in right shift bitwise operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
int main()
{

    int x = 0xff0000ff;
    int N_BITS = sizeof (int) * 8;  /* 32 */
    int l = 0x0;

    printf ("Right shift expected result: %x\n", 0x80000000 >> (31));

    l = (x & (0x00000001 << (N_BITS - 1)));
    printf ("l = %x\n", l);

    /* Right Shift l by 31 bits */
    l = l >> 31;
    printf ("l after right shift by 31 bits: %x\n", l);
}
~
```

Output:

```
Right shift expected result: 1
l = 80000000
l after right shift by 31 bits: ffffffff
```

~
The right shift of 0x80000000 by 31 bits should result in 0x00000001 as shown in the very first output. Why the output is different here when the variable `l` is shifted by 31 bits to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the result of

```
l = (x & (0x00000001 << (N_BITS - 1)));
```

is `0x80000000` (see below it is not guaranteed as the expression invokes undefined behavior).

In two's complement system, `0x80000000` is a negative value (`INT_MIN`).

```
l = l >> 31;
```

C says this `>>` operation is implementation-defined. In your system it performs sign extension: the sign bit is propagated.

> (C11, 6.5.7p4) "If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined."

Finally on why:

```
0x000001 << (N_BITS - 1)
```

invokes undefined behavior.

From the horse mouth (emphasis mine):

> (C11, 6.5.7p4) "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^^E2, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**"

Comment: I am not clear about the explanation. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @SumitTrehan To summarize, do not perform bitwise shift on values of signed types like `int`. Use unsigned types.

Comment: Why 0x00000001 << 31 is an undefined behaviour then, as 0x0000001 is an unsigned number?

Comment: @SumitTrehan - If the msb(most significant bit) is set then on right
shifting the bits the msb is copied into all the bits you have shifted.
This is the case when you use signed integers, to avoid this you   
should perform bitwise shift operations on unsigned integers.

Comment: @SumitTrehan `0x00000001` is of type `int`, `0x00000001U` is of type `unsigned int`.